# return result from stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to get a resultset from a mysql stored procedure in php. how can i do that? any help is appreciated. preferably if someone can post a code snippet!
For example, if I have a login table. I have created a stored procedure which does

```
SELECT * FROM login
```

Now I need to call this stored procedure in php and iterate over the resultset

Comment: Why didn't you [googled for such thing, for example: Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: or go to http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "quadv2_dev");

if (!$mysqli->multi_query("CALL testlist()")) {
    echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        printf("---\n<pre/>");
        print_r($res->fetch_all());
        $res->free();
    } else {
        if ($mysqli->errno) {
            echo "Store failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

mysql :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `quadv2_dev`.`testlist`()
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN

    SET @Qry ="SELECT *  FROM Content";
    PREPARE st FROM @Qry;
    EXECUTE st;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```